# Модификаторы доступа конструктора

Tags: java

Я правильно понимаю, что у созданного класса, конструктор по умолчанию имеет модификатор доступа package private?

Answer (score 1):

Модификатор доступа у конструктора по умолчанию зависит от модификатора доступа класса.

[Chapter 8. Classes - 8.8.9. Default Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> The default constructor has the same access modifier as the class, unless the class lacks an access modifier, in which case the default constructor has package access (§6.6).